# .wslconfig not applied for WSL2

Tags: windows, wsl2

In the wsl2 [docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl-config#configure-global-options-with-wslconfig) it is said that wsl can be configured with `%USERPROFILE%/.wslconfig`
I created that file and set memory limit to **2Gb**. But after running `wsl --shutdown` and then starting ubuntu in wsl again and running a couple of processes inside(additonally started docker which is configured to run on wsl2 and which creates additional 2 instances in wsl) it I see in Task manager that `Vmmem` process is taking **much more than 2GB**. I'm running on win10 home edition, version 20H2

What did I do wrong? Are there some pitfalls in this process

**EDIT**
Checked on Windows 10 Pro - works. Doesn't work on Home edition

Comment: But what about the memory usage _inside_? Virtualization does have overhead.

Comment: Is it possible you are seeing the total memory of WSL and the VM?

Comment: htop command inside ubuntu always shows that 12GB is availabale for me(my laptop has 16 GB of RAM)

Comment: @DanielB when I wrote *much more* I meant  twice as more and even more. Not sure that this because of virtualization overhead

Comment: I have Windows 10 Pro (20H2) and it seems the .wslconfig setting for processors does work but not the one for memory. Any idea?

Comment: @BlazingFrog see my answer to this question. Maybe this also a cause for you

Answer (score 3):

I've had the same problem of WSL not respecting the memory limits set in .wslconfig.

It turns out, [the WSL is sensitive to BOM in the config file](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/5389). I saved it as UTF-8 without BOM and it started working.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was that I misspelled measure of magnitude for memory: instead of `GB` I wrote `Gb`. This is important for wslconfig