# Docker on Windows is very slow

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows

I have a Docker on Windows 10 which uses Ubuntu 20, WSL2, ... but it is very slow.
I tried to set up confuguration in .wslconfig file which looks like

```
# Limits VM memory to use no more than 4 GB, this can be set as whole numbers using GB or MB
memory=8GB 

# Sets the VM to use two virtual processors
processors=4

# Sets amount of swap storage space to 8GB, default is 25% of available RAM
swap=12GB
```

I have a 16GB RAM on PC so I set up 12GB but docker desctop still shows me 4GB. What can I do to increase performance?

This is the only information about config in docker desctop.

[image]

Comment: You set the swap to 12GB not the memory. Where exactly did you put the WSL configuration file? [You did restart your machine, right?](https://superuser.com/questions/1632543/wslconfig-not-applied-for-wsl2)

Comment: This was an example file which I found somewhere including the comments. So swap should be RAM but really dont understand what and why memory is 8GB. What should be real walues?

Comment: Yes I did restart machine and .wslconfig in in users/username/ directory

Comment: My PC has 16GB RAM so I would like to use it. Disc is ssd with full of free space. So what means memory 8GB. Its nothing....

Comment: May be I created .wslconfig manually. But docker desctop does not show any usefull info about config only link to microsoft web page.

Comment: Yes; You always have to create .wslconfig manually

Comment: So what, how can I see what are the settings for resouces in docker desctop? As you can see on screenshot there is not usefull info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in this case was not the memory. The problem was that whole project vendor direcotry was in volumes. After removing vendor from volumes everything is ok.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced similar slow performance issues in windows 10/11 with Docker desktop and WSL2. My solution was when we map the physical volume to container volume, the physical volume should be inside the WSL filesystem except the /mnt.

For e.g in my docker-compose.yaml, I had a line

```
volumes:
      - /var/www/vhosts:/var/www/html
```

The "**/var/www/vhosts**" was inside the WSL filesystem. Once I configured this way my apps were lighting fast.